# zClip copy text inside `<u>` on self-click without altering appearance

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, zclip

jQuery:

```
$('div.sel-u u').click(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  $(this).zclip({
    path: 'js/ZeroClipboard.swf',
    copy: $this.text()
  });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="sel-u">
  <u>Click to copy me</u> and <u>then me</u>
</div>
```

Clicking once makes the text disappear, and clicking a second time copies it.

How can I get this to simply copy the element on first click without altering its appearance?